# athena column contains list type data

Tags: sql, presto

Have a Athena table like this:

```
userid    visited
001a       ['New York','Los Angeles']
002b       ['Atlanta']
0030       ['New York','Paris','Albany']
....
```

Not quite sure how to query such list type column.
How could I find

1. users who visited 'New York', desired:

```
0001a 
00030
```

2. all distinct cities visited? desired output:

```
'New York'
'Los Angeles'
'Paris'
'Atlanta'
'Albany'
```

Comment: What is the data type of `visited`?  Also, two questions is one too many for a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `visited` is array type from presto:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
             VALUES ('001a',       ARRAY['New York','Los Angeles']),
                    ('002b',       ARRAY['Atlanta', 'Los Angeles'])
         ) AS t (id, visited))
```

For the first one use [`contains`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#contains) function:

```sql
select id
from dataset
where contains(visited, 'Atlanta'); -- returns 002b
```

for the second one you can use [`set_union`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#set_union) function, but it is not available for me in Athena (or I'm using it wrong =), so you can workaround with:

```sql
select array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(visited)))
from dataset; -- returns `{New York,Los Angeles,Atlanta}`
```

If `visited` is a string you can turn it into array via casting it to JSON and then [to array](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-from-json).